# error: cannot find symbol import androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout; after migrating to androidx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

when i migrate to androidx then
error - error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
^
symbol:   class SwipeRefreshLayout
location: package androidx.core.widget

```
here is my code details, Please help me ....

package com.app.exammantra.activities;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.exammantra.Config;
import com.app.exammantra.R;
import com.app.exammantra.utilities.GDPR;
import com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class ActivityPdfView extends AppCompatActivity {

int position;
WebView webview;
String str_title, str_url;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_view);

if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
}

swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue, R.color.red);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    position = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);
    str_title = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE");
    str_url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

    //Toast.makeText(this, str_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(str_title);
    }

    loadBannerAd();

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // web settings
    webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
    webview.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    webview.setFocusable(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    webview.setLongClickable(false);

    //webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + str_url);

    webview.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
                webview.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Connect   Network!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        view.loadUrl("about:blank");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onFinishReadBook();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
    return true;
}

public void loadBannerAd() {
    if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_BANNER_ADS) {
        MobileAds.initialize(ActivityPdfView.this, getResources().getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new   AdRequest.Builder().addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class,GDPR.getBundleAd(ActivityPdfView.this)).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void onFinishReadBook() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityPdfView.this);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_dialog_finish_reading);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_dialog_finish_reading));
    dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.option_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.option_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

}



My build.gradle file

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.6'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.app.exammantra'

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "75e9ef33-cc67-4ae3-8b4f-1ab09c874ae1",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

i googled it  and try some ans but not getting any solution. Hope here i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [correct package](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) is:

```
androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```